# How do I link d3dx9?

Tags: c++, directx-9

I compiled a DirectX program with g++ via the command line and it worked just fine. When I included d3dx9.h, I got the all too familiar "no such file or directory" message. As it turns out, the linker "cannot find -ld3dx9". I checked, and the necessary files are in their proper directories. The include and lib files are properly flagged. The compiler takes the -ld3d9 flag just fine, but apparently -ld3dx9 does not fly. I tried it in CodeBlocks and the same thing happened. It worked just fine and dandy for some fellow on YouTube. I must be missing something extremely obvious.

**edit:** Here is what I give the compiler. I'm on 64 bit Windows 7.

```
g++ Wrap.cpp winmain.cpp -o test
-IC:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MicrosoftDirectXSDK(June2010)\Include
-LC:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MicrosoftDirectXSDK(June2010)\Lib\x64
-ld3d9 -ld3dx9 -mwindows
```

and here's the includes in the file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
```

Comment: Not linker. Its compiler complaining about header file. Please add your include directories correctly.

Comment: @Digital_Reality It is unclear if the d3dx9.h file can not be found by the compiler or if the d3dx9 lib can not be found by the linker. Or both. More information on the directory structure, file locations, `include` statements and compiler flags would be helpful.

Comment: which toolchain you used? mingw or mingw-w64? for example, in mingw-w64, there are a lot of revision of d3dx9, like libd3dx9_24.a libd3dx9_35.a, specified one and it may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *really* have a directory named `ProgramFiles(x86)`?  You should quote or escape spaces in the command.  For example, something like this might work:

```
g++ ... "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include"
```